# How to install ClamAV on Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: installation, 12.10, clamav

I am new to Ubuntu, so I am not sure how to install ClamAV on my Ubuntu which is version 12.10.

Comment: Just stick to Avast or BitDefender. Or any other Linux compatible product. Implying, you are going to use it on Desktop.

Answer (score 8):

> Clam AntiVirus is an anti-virus toolkit for Unix. The main purpose of
>   this software is the integration with mail servers (attachment
>   scanning). The package provides a flexible and scalable multi-threaded
>   daemon in the clamav-daemon package, a command-line scanner in the
>   clamav package, and a tool for automatic updating via the Internet in
>   the clamav-freshclam package. The programs are based on libclamav6,
>   which can be used by other software.<sup>1</sup>

To install ClamAV, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the commands below.

```
sudo apt-get install clamav clamtk
```

Once its done Type clam in Dash, and click on calmTK to start the application.

[image]

[image]

You may have to do an update.  Just run `sudo freshclam` in terminal to update definitions.

To update the program [Click Here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/clamtk/files/ClamTk/4.44/clamtk_4.44-1_all.deb/download) to download the file, once downloaded, go the download location, right click on the file, and choose Open With Ubuntu Software Center

[image]

[image]

And click on Update.

<sup><sup>**1**</sup>Source:[Ubuntu Apps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H80EB.png)</sup>