# Isolation Program or just good antivirus?

Tags: 12.10, software-recommendation, antivirus

A friend of mine just got her computer back from her sister. It's running windows and was ate up with mal-ware and viruses. I think I've pretty much sanitized it but some of those files are about to make a stop on my system running Ub12.10. I'm being cautious and want to find a condom for the files. Is there a program to quarantine questionable files? Or, do I just need to make sure I have an antivirus and anti mal-ware that work? If so where can I get them for 12.10?

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/282452/how-to-install-clamav-on-ubuntu-12-10/282471#282471) it might help.

Comment: Viruses are not much of an issue on Linux [see here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Antivirus).  The antivirus products that do exist are mainly there to protect Windows machines.